# Solving a recurrence relation with constraints

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

I have the following recurrence relation with complex coefficients:

```
c[n] == Sqrt[n-1] c[n-1] + Sqrt[n] c[n+1]
```

I also have the constraint that

$\sum_n |c_n|^2 = 1$

Unfortunately, `RSolve` doesn't give me a solution.

Ideally, I would like to find the (numerical) distribution of these coefficients for which $\sum_n n |c_n|^2 = \bar{n}$, where I can choose $\bar{n}$ as I like. However, I am not sure if solutions exist for arbitrary chosen $\bar{n}$.

Comment: If you have a solution with a finite absolute sum, you can scale it to sum to 1

Comment: Is the constraint $\,|c_1|^2+|c_2|^2+\dots=1?\,$ Your $\,\sum_n\,$ is not explicit enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the limit of large `n`, the recurrence relation reduces to `c[n+1] == -c[n-1]]`. Consequently, the sum in the question is unbounded unless `c[n] == 0` for some finite `n` and beyond. However, this implies that all `c[n]` vanish, unless a coefficient in the recurrence relation also vanishes at the same value of `n` that the particular `c[n]` vanishes.  There is only one value of `n` for which a coefficient vanishes, namely `n = 1`, in which case,

```
RecurrenceTable[{c[n] == Sqrt[n - 1] c[n - 1] + Sqrt[n] c[n + 1], 
    c[1] == 0, c[0] == 1}, c, {n, 10}]
(* {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

The sequence beginning with `c[0] == -1` also satisfies the constraint, of course.

I do not believe that there are any other such sequences.  For instance,

```
RecurrenceTable[{c[n] == Sqrt[n - 1] c[n - 1] + Sqrt[n] c[n + 1], 
    c[1] == 1., c[0] == 0}, c, {n, 9999989, 10000000}]
(* {-0.00529902, 0.0196947, 0.00530525, -0.019693 , 
    -0.00531147, 0.0196914, 0.0053177 , -0.0196897, 
    -0.00532393, 0.019688 , 0.00533015, -0.0196863} *)
```